# Custom Properties Via Python Don't Display

Tags: python, properties

As of 2.79, custom properties assigned via Python no longer display in the Properties Panel. I've confirmed that the properties are indeed being assigned to the objects (by checking them via a Python console) but they don't show up in the UI. I've run my addon in 2.78c and the custom properties show in the UI as they always have.

Is this by design? If so, is there a way to have custom properties that have been assigned via Python show up in the UI so they can be seen/changed?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you assigning these custom properties?

Comment: I'm iterating through a dictionary:

def setCustomProperties(ob, propsVals):
    for prop in propsVals:
        ob[prop] = propsVals[prop] 
    return True

Comment: This works for me in official 2.79 release.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I'll have to look into this closer; something's weird.